# Analayis is giving an error to an needed constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

'variable' is final and was given a value when it was declared,so it can't be set to a new value.Try removing one of the initializations.
This is the error that keep giving.How can I remove the error?I need it for a http post request.

```
  Future<User> fetchUser() async {
  final response =
  await http.get('https://coronavirus-med.herokuapp.com/api/v1/auth/register');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load request');
  }
}

  class User{
  final String name = ' ';
  final String email = ' ';
  final String password = ' ';
  final String passwordConfirm = ' ';
  final String role = ' ';

  User({this.name, this.email, this.password, this.passwordConfirm, this.role});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return User(
      name: json['name'],
      email: json['email'],
      password: json['password'],
      passwordConfirm: json['passwordConfirm'],
      role: json['role'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `User` class like this

```
class User {
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final String passwordConfirm;
  final String role;

  User({
    String name,
    String email,
    String password,
    String passwordConfirm,
    String role,
  })  : this.name = name ?? ' ',
        this.email = email ?? ' ',
        this.password = password ?? ' ',
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm ?? ' ',
        this.role = role ?? ' ';

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      name: json['name'],
      email: json['email'],
      password: json['password'],
      passwordConfirm: json['passwordConfirm'],
      role: json['role'],
    );
  }
}
```